# Equivalent of roxygen2's #' @importFrom but using a pattern to match function names

Tags: r, roxygen2

Let's say I want to import all the `scale_*` and `geom_*` functions from *ggplot2*, and all the `*_at`, `*_if`, `*_all` functions from dplyr, but I don't want to type those by hand and would rather use regular expressions.

I have a couple ideas that I might post as answers if I don't get anything better coming :

- Create a function that edits the NAMESPACE file, run it, remove the function from the workspace
- Create programmatically a file containing the `#' @importFrom ggplot2 scale_x_continuous ...` instructions.

Is there something better of a current implementation of this already ?

Comment: Interesting problem. You mean something like this - `ls(getNamespace("ggplot2"), pattern = "^scale_.*")`?

Comment: yes, this would probably be part of the code if we need to code something

Comment: A third approach might be to extend *rogygen2* but I have no idea how to go at that

Comment: Your suggested solution to programmatically create a file and link it with `#' @rdname` seems like a way to go.

Comment: And to keep it close to `roxygen2` you can `roxygen2:::roxy_tag_ns.roxy_tag_importFrom(list(val = c("ggplot2", ls(getNamespace("ggplot2"), pattern = "^scale_.*"))))`

Comment: I have done something similar before - creating roxygen2 comments and then linking R files using `rdname` (https://github.com/bd-R/bdchecks/blob/524c6f0a1eb5c0a1b9790dcb541cc0ef65bc81f0/R/class_export.R#L51)